# Sharing data context by all my repositories using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC3 solution where I have 2 repositories & 2 service layers. I also have separate every layer: controller <--> service <--> repository

Previously, in each of my repositories I had a separate data context. I mean I created a new object instance in each repository. I knew **this is not the good way**.

So I refactored my solution in order to share my data context between my repositories. Below is the skeleton of my solution. I would like your opinion.

```
public class EntityFrameworkDbContext: DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public DbSet<Project>           Projects            { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Technology>        Technologies        { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        SaveChanges();
    }
}

public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Save();
}
```

The nInject bindings

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<EntityFrameworkDbContext>().InRequestScope();
ninjectKernel.Bind<IMainRepository>().To<MainRepository>();
ninjectKernel.Bind<IAdminRepository>().To<AdminRepository>();
ninjectKernel.Bind<IMainService>().To<MainService>();
ninjectKernel.Bind<IAdminService>().To<AdminService>();
```

Controller

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private IMainService m_MainService;
    private IAdminService m_AdminService;

    public AdminController(IMainService mainService, IAdminService adminService)
    {
        m_MainService = mainService;
        m_AdminService = adminService;
    }
    ...
}
```

Service

```
public class MainService : IMainService
{
    private IMainRepository m_Repository;

    public MainService(IMainRepository repository)
    {
        m_Repository = repository;
    }
    ...
}
```

Repository

```
public class AdminRepository : IAdminRepository 
{
    private EntityFrameworkDbContext m_Context;

    public AdminRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        if (unitOfWork == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("unitOfWork");

        m_Context = unitOfWork as EntityFrameworkDbContext;
    }
    ...
}
```

As you can see I implement the Unit of Work pattern but I don't know if this is a good approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used a similar approach with MVC3 and Linq2SQL, so I guess this should work for Entity Framework too. Just make sure that you tell the fact to other developers, that by default all queries in the same request use the same EF DbContext if not told otherwise.

One remark: You are effectively casting your `IUnitOfWork` to a `EntityFrameworkDbContext` type in your Repository, and I guess you couldn't just replace it with another implementation. Is it a good idea to publish to the callers, that you expect `IUnitOfWork` (that has 1 method), but under the hood your code works only, if you pass an `EntityFrameworkDbContext`? And I would guess code would fail, if the parameter is not an actual `EntityFrameworkDbContext`?

If you use that actual EF datacontext, you can pass in an actual `EntityFrameworkDbContext` instance to all callers using Ninject like this:

```
//this makes sure all contexts use the same DbContext
ninjectKernel.Bind<EntityFrameworkDbContext>().To<EntityFrameworkDbContext>().InRequestScope();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I didn't understand very well your code ninjectKernel.Bind<EntityFrameworkDbContext>().To<EntityFrameworkDbContext>().InRequestScope(); Do you mean with this simple bind, data context will be shared? I already implement Unit Of Work in that purpose...

Comment: Yes, it means exactly that. Your code asks for an EntityFrameworkDbContext type, it will get an instance of EntityFrameworkDbContext. And RequestScope ensures that it will be the same instance in any given Http request. Makes UnitOfWork kind of redundant if you use it only for that purpose...

Comment: Also, seeing IUnitOfWork, and Repository in the same code just makes me think about this [article  by Rob Connery](http://wekeroad.com/2011/06/30/a-simple-example-thats-incredibly-complex/). Suggest you read it, and decide if it applies to your current situation.

Comment: Very interesting article. I removed all about UnitOfWork in my solution and tested it. You are right, I don't need it at this moment in my solution. Your solution works pretty well. Thank you anymay.

Comment: What would be the downside to using this to deal with EF launching two different contexts to pull two different entities (and the problems that arise from that?)

Comment: I assume that you read from two databases (if the two datacontexts read from the same db, that would by totally pointless i think), then distributed transactions and things like that can create pretty "interesting" bugs/deadlock/etc. So I think in that case, managing transactions across two databases would be the bigger problem. But you can "hack" more databases into one EF context (create synonyms in the db, and put all tables into 1 datacontext) to avoid using two datacontexts. If that's possible in you scenario.